# Change Woocommerce Bookings Datepicker to Time table

Tags: php, html, woocommerce

Is it possible to change the woocommerce bookings datepicker, which is displayed at the single product page, to a time table where you only see the days Monday through Friday without any date or month given. I would like it so that if you click on any of the days it shows you the hours at which the room is available.

I tried playing a bit with the datepicker but haven't yet found a sufficent solution for the problem.

I'm more than grateful for any help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! I know exactly nothing about woocommerce, but, in general, the people who do know the answer need to see what you have so far. See [ask].

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use a date picker to show all the dates on which bookings are available.
Show all the dates in white color and if on a  particular date bookings are available highlight it with green and if on that day bookings are not possible, highlight it with red.
Make your own custom table, doing this gives you the freedom to edit everything.

Comment: The idea is that one of our rentables can only be rent for at least half a year for the same time every week. Thus, I want to create a time table that displays only the days. If someone were to say book a specific time on Tuesday, this time will not be available for the next 6 months. That's why dates are of no use and because I want to make it easier for the customers to understand, I want to change the datepicker to a time table.

Comment: Oh I got it! Make an HTML table (dynamically generated with PHP) and use JS to CSS it after the page gets loaded.